# Create Piwik plugin which extends device-detector plugin

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, matomo

I tryed to creat a Piwik plugin based on DeviceDetection plugin
There is a point that I didn't understood, and I hope that one of you can help me.

this Plugin will add some new features to the detection system.

But I have a question.
How can I make it interacting with te current version of deviceDetection.
Because right now I already did a module, and the module work by himself, but I would like that he just add informations to devicedetection

Thank you